# SQL Server Write Permission but not delete

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, permissions

I'm pretty sure the answer is that once I grant write/alter access it explicitly gives the person access to delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty straight forward to do this AND to test it which you really should do before you post a question.

```
GRANT INSERT TO YourUser
GRANT SELECT TO YourUser
GRANT UPDATE TO YourUser
DENY DELETE TO YourUser
```

Comment: thanks, I've been thinking about it for a few days, and it I was at the answer but never tested it, ill be sure to test it next go around. haha

Answer (score 3):

For data; Insert, Update & Delete are all separate permissions.  Granting db_datawriter  is a role that grants all three, but you can grant them individually if you choose.

Select is also a distinct permission.  You can technically grant someone the ability to only insert data, without the ability to select/update/delete.

For objects; Create, Alter, Drop are the separate permissions.

Comment: I didn't think Drop was a permission? I am looking to deny dropping tables, but still want to allow Users to delete rows from in the table.

Comment: db_datawriter allows to delete the data, see my answer above.  db_ddladmin allows modifying objects, such as dropping a table.  Make sure they have the first role and not the second.  Even better is to create a custom named role, assign permissions and roles to it and make them a member of it.  It provides you much better control.